# When I add a view using AutoLayout to a UIScrollView as a subview, everything looks wrong

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

My application contains a form that is presented to the user as a subview of a UIScrollView. The form view is controlled by a FormViewController. The UIScrollView takes up the whole screen. The form view has a height of 800 points and a width equal to the screen width. I want to place the form 70% towards the bottom of the screen, to let the user see an image below the scroll view. The form view contains labels, text fields, and other views all constrained using AutoLayout. The background of the form is white.

When I add the form view as a subview however, the labels show up above the main form area, in the area where the background is not white. This is what I'm using to add the form view to the UIScrollView in Swift:

```
func setUpForm() {
    self.formContentHeight = 0
    self.formContentHeight += CGFloat(Int(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height * 0.7))
    var form:FormViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("formviewcontroller") as! FormViewController
    form.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.formContentHeight, self.formContentWidth, 800)
    self.formScrollView.addSubview(form.view)
    self.formContentHeight += 800
    self.formScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.formContentWidth, self.formContentHeight)
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

When I simply present the FormViewController using presentViewController(), everything is fine:

```
func setUpForm() {
    presentViewController(form, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Result:

[image]

Here's the FormViewController in the Storyboard:

[image]

What could be happening here?

Comment: Storyboard screenshot doesn't show backgroundColor of your view controller's view, most likely it is transparent.

Comment: No, the background is definitely white. You can tell because in the first screenshot I posted, the background is white starting at 70% of the way down the screen, where the form is indeed supposed to start. The problem is that the labels are too high up for some reason.